# Want to put textures on the phrase in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to put textures on the phrase I created.
However, currently my code does not have texture mapping. 
It only opens a warning that the file cannot be opened when it runs.
Why? And please fix it.

```
void view() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glutSolidSphere(0.4, 20, 20);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned int id;
    AUX_RGBImageRec *texture;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    GLfloat plane_coef_s[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat plane_coef_t[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
    glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_OBJECT_PLANE, plane_coef_s);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
    glTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_OBJECT_PLANE, plane_coef_t);
    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricTexture(sphere, GL_TRUE);
    tex = auxDIBImageLoad("test.bmp");
    glGenTextures(2, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, tex->sizeX, tex->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->data);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
}
```

Comment: Usually because the file is not in the application's current working directory.

Comment: I'll give it a try :)

Comment: Consider rewording your question. Just throwing out some code and asking strangers to "fix it" is non-productive at best and can be considered rude at worst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure the text.bmp file is in the same location as the .cpp file.

`glutSolidSphere (0.4, 20);` does not seem to have texture mapping.
Declares `GLUquadric *sphere;` as a global variable and change
`glugSphere (sphere, 0.4, 20, 20);`.

And you have to declare these two variables as global variables.

So, switch to the code below.

```
unsigned int id;
AUX_RGBImageRec *texture;
GLUquadric *sphere;

void view() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    gluSphere(sphere, 0.4, 20, 20);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(1200, 800);
    glutCreateWindow("test");
    GLfloat plane_coef_s[] = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    GLfloat plane_coef_t[] = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S);
    glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
    glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_OBJECT_PLANE, plane_coef_s);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T);
    glTexGeni(GL_T, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_OBJECT_LINEAR);
    glTexGenfv(GL_T, GL_OBJECT_PLANE, plane_coef_t);
    sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricTexture(sphere, GL_TRUE);
    tex = auxDIBImageLoad("test.bmp");
    glGenTextures(2, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, tex->sizeX, tex->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex->data);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
}
```